# Find the radius of a circle that is inscribed inside of a triangle given the sides of the triangle

Tags: geometry

It's not hard, but I can't remember how to do this.

**Suppose there is a triangle with sides $a=10,b=17,c=21$. If we draw a circle inside of this triangle, what will it be its radius $r$?**

If it's not clear what I'm asking, just tell me and I'll draw a picture of this problem and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle inscribed in a triangle is called an [in-circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle). If you read the section on in-circle and the area of the triangle in the web link, you will find a useful formula:

$\triangle area =$ radius of incircle $\cdot \frac{{\rm perimeter\ of } \triangle}{2}$

You can find the area of the $\triangle$ given the sides from [Heron's formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the area of the triangle is half of the product of the radius and triangle perimeter